# Is there a way to use Google App Script to navigate between the thumbnails in the Slides filmstrip?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

Is there a way to use Google App Script to change from one slide to another in a presentation while editing it?

Comment: There are no onClick event objects in the list [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_slides_events) in the Slides section of the event objects documentation.  So I'd say no.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you want cannot be achieved because there are **no** `onEdit()` triggers available for Google Slides. The only types of triggers available are:

- `onOpen()` triggers;
- `onInstall()` triggers;
- `time-driven` triggers;

What you can do instead is to file a **Feature Request** on Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and provide all the necessary details.

**Reference**

- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to allow javascript in the side panel html to update the hash in the browser URL?

Is there a way to flag the sandbox to allow-top-navigation ?

Currently, I get the following error when trying this:
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://docs.google.com' from frame with URL 'https://n-***************-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150840775

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#selectascurrentpage

So, please consider this closed.